# Non-English Characters are being converted to Decimal

Tags: python, xml, utf-8, decimal, non-english

While I was checking an RSS feed, in a browser I can see the text as below:

> 装，配上超短迷你裙，太过暴露，也很不得体。大专学生的随性打扮...

But the same source code view is converted to decimal as below:

```html
#30701&#35044&#12289&#36855&#20320&#35033&#12289&#21514&#24102&#35013&#12289&#20154&#23383&#25302&#38795&#46;&#46;&#46;&#46;&#46;&#46;&#22823&#19

987&#23398&#29983&#30340&#31359&#30528&#25171&#25198&#21450&#28526&#27969&#21697&#21619&#65292&#19968&#30452&#37117&#26159&#26159&#22823&#23478&#35752&#35770&#30340&#2

8909&#38376&#35805&#39064&#12290&
```

Is this due to localization of the content or the file is saved in different encoding? I can see the the file is saved using UTF-8.

I am trying to parse the RSS feed using Python. But after parsing, I am only getting the decimal values, not the actual characters.

Comment: They are missing the ';' I think

Comment: @xanatos, Thet have not added anything in the code. The browser display the contents well , but when I see the code it shows the Decimal Chars . Why the thai chars get converted to decinal?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, these are not Thai characters.

Comment: @Serge - appTranslator, Changed to NonEnglish

Answer (score 2):

It's not that the source view is converting it to decimal - it's that the browser is handling the entities and converting them to the relevant non-ASCII characters. It's possible that it's being a little generous in terms of converting entities which don't have a terminating ';'.

The server is almost certainly serving what you're seeing in the source view.

Comment: But when I save RSS feed to a local XML file and try to open with the browser then I can not see the Thai Chars. But I see the  decimal values!!! [RSS Link](http://www.omy.sg/global/feeds/homefeeds/omy_yzone_latest_all.rss "Thai RSS")

Comment: @Subhen: Possibly due to the semi-colons being missing? Perhaps the browser is being more forgiving when fetching remotely...

Comment: Added the semi-colons manually , but still I see the decimal chars only

Comment: @Subhen: Well, the browser *should* be performing the replacement as far as I'm aware. It's also not clear that this is really an appropriate Stack Overflow question - what's the coding angle?

Comment: Edited the question. I am trying to parse the feed using python

Comment: @Subhen: Okay, so you probably want to write something to clean up the feed first, fixing `&#[digits]` into that entity first.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the tool that created the feed decided to convert all characters to their Unicode code point string representation. Odd indeed but only the author of that tool can answer.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't they just stored as HTML entities by the author of the page?

http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/thaichart.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how the browser handles this. Write simple html page, put this 'decimal' there and check what you get.

Yes, you can use UTF-8 characters in HTML, but you must then set page encoding. Encoding UTF-8 characters decimally, such as in you example, is simply safer, so many pages prefer to do it so. It is specified in HTML standards, so if you wish to parse HTML manually, you must be able to deal with it.